# What is the future currency design in the "Minority Report" tv series?

Tags: minority-report

In the first episode glimpses of money did not look like our bills, and I wondered if it was Canadian, but the show is set in Washington DC.  In episode 4 was a better view ([Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) posted a screen grab in an Answer), and I could see that someone imagined a future evolved design for what bills (Treasury Notes) would look like.

Does anyone have a pointer to details concerning this design?  I mean, was there a *behind the scenes* article or bonus content that describes **how the design was created and the artist's thoughts behind it**?

Comment: Thanks, @Richard.  I don't have a timestamp and I didn't save the episode.  There is a clear view when a bag of money is dumped out, but not quite enough to read it in detail. I thought one large word was cursive "Australia" but that doesn't make sense.  I did not find anything relevant with Google.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see me address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: If you want it, you can buy it online here; http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Minority-Report-500-Obama-Prop-Bill-with-Stand-and-COA-/182143064101

Answer (score 4):

The future currency is an original prop and features [Obama on the $500 bill](http://newsbusters.org/blogs/culture/alexa-moutevelis-coombs/2015/10/13/minority-report-features-obama-500-dollar-bill)

[image]

Mixed in with the fake notes are some real Australian currency, including a real A$100 bill featuring [Dame Nellie Melba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nellie_Melba).

[image]

Comment: I guess posts are appearing *after* I searched for it, inspired by the same scene.  That blog post said "the lasy is Australian" but I think that's just someone else in my position looking at the frame; not any information from the artist etc.

Comment: Looks like a woman on the $100 bill too.

Comment: @Xantec - Yep. 'Tis